# RDS SQL Server - Reducing used storage after dropping column

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I have a table that uses 600GB of the storage, and I dropped a column that takes I believe a half of this whole storage - Redundant column now.
I want to migrate this database into a newer RDS with lower allocated storage.
However, I can't see that there is more freed space in RDS "FreeStorageSpace" monitor, after dropping the column.

What am I missing? What can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: The space isn't recovered automatically, you would need to rebuild the clustered index and then attempt to shrink the data file.

Comment: I didn't work with the  AWS, but in the sql server, by deleting the table and field, the space will not back os(but dB can use this space and Part of the unused space is the database ) unless that file group of that table, if it doesn't have it, shrink default group file itself.that shrink doesn't recommand

Comment: @Stu ALTER INDEX ALL ON <table-name> REBUILD is the right command to rebuild the indexes? After it, how can I get and shrink the data file?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117391/claiming-disk-space-after-removing-table-field You need to first do either `DBCC CLEANTABLE` or a rebuild of all indexes, (depending on whether you dropped a variable length column or not), and the do `DBCC SHRINKFILE` to get the space back